# Store references to instance methods in a static context

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to have a `static` map where the values are instance methods. Someting like:

```
public class MyClass {
    static Map<MyEnum, Consumer<String>> methodMapping;
    static {
        methodMapping = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);

        methodMapping.put(MyEnum.FIRST, MyClass::firstMethod);
        methodMapping.put(MyEnum.SECOND, MyClass::secondMethod);
    }
    void firstMethod(String param) {
        ...
    }
    void secondMethod(String param) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This gives me an error saying "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". I understand why this would be a problem if I would try to call the methods from the static context, but isn't it possible from an instance method to retrieve the method from the map and pass it `this`? Like:

`MyClass.methodMapping.get(MyEnum.FIRST).accept(this, "string");`

Comment: That design looks a bit funky. Care to explain the thoughts behind this enum-to-method mapping?

Comment: @Kayaman Refactoring purposes, there was a long switch in an instance method, calling different methods from each branch. I didn't want to create that many subclasses for just one method in each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solvable as easy as changing `Consumer` to `BiConsumer`, turning the receiver instance of `MyClass` to a parameter of the function:

```
public class MyClass {
    static Map<MyEnum, BiConsumer<MyClass,String>> methodMapping;
    static {
        methodMapping = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);

        methodMapping.put(MyEnum.FIRST,  MyClass::firstMethod);
        methodMapping.put(MyEnum.SECOND, MyClass::secondMethod);
    }
    void firstMethod(String param) {
        ...
    }
    void secondMethod(String param) {
        ...
    }
    void callTheMethod(MyEnum e, String s) {
        methodMapping.get(e).accept(this, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very intresting and usable answer. But i have a same question. If instead of `BiConsumer<MyClass, String>` i want to have this `BiConsumer<SomeInterface, String>` (Example init: `BiCosumer<Interface, String> bi_consumer = ImplInterface::some_method;`). I try to do this, but still get "non-static method reference in static context" I found, that i can do like this `Consumer<String> consumer = (s) -> new ImplInterface().some_method(s);`, but i need to have interfaces in program. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @MrBin you have a mismatch in the specified classes `ImplInterface::some_method` requires the receiver type to be of the particular implementation class `ImplInterface`, hence, can’t consume arbitrary `Interface` instances. When the method is declared in the interface, just use `BiConsumer<Interface, String> x = Interface::some_method;`. Otherwise, you can only define a consumer for the particular implementation class, `BiConsumer<ImplInterface, String> x = ImplInterface::some_method;`. You may just check with `BiConsumer<Interface, String> x = (receiver, string) -> receiver.some_method(s);`…

Answer (score 2):

You initialize `methodMapping` in a **static initialization block**. At that point, your *instance* methods can't be referred to yet because you haven't called `new MyClass()` yet.

You could fix this by either making your methods static, or moving the methodMapping initialization from the static block to a constructor.

PS: The keyword **static** can be omitted from the initialization  block

Comment: Sorry, but @Holger's solution was exactly what I was looking for, so I accepted his answer instead

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't understand that

```
static Map<MyEnum, Consumer<String>> methodMapping;
  static {
```

does exactly that,  trying to call the methods from the static context where they don't exist.

The key thing to understand here: you intend to create a **method reference**; and a method reference needs some object to invoke that method on. Thus there is no "delaying"; there is no way in java to express "wait for `this` to be meaningful"; or in other words: there is no way in a static context to express: "you will be used in a non-static context later on; and then pick the corresponding `this` from there".

Comment: You probably are right. What I don't get about it is that you already know that every instance is going to have these methods. Why can't you specify who `this` is later, since you don't want the methods to be executed while you are in the static initialization block.

Comment: But you need that **object** at that point; because you want to create a "reference" to a method on a **specific** object.

Comment: There you go, I was waiting to see where the discussion goes

Comment: You are welcome; I tried to put my thoughts into my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm coming from objc background, where this thing makes sense (you specify the method name and the receiver in 2 separate parameters when trying to call it this way)

Answer (score 1):

> isn't it possible from an instance method to retrieve the method from the map and pass it `this`

No. A `Consumer` only has a single parameter `accept()` method, so there's no such thing as "passing `this` at calling time".

You need an instance when creating the method reference, so this questions boils down to "can't call instance method from a static context".

Comment: What I don't get about it is that you already know that every instance is going to have these methods. Why can't you specify who this is later, since you don't want the methods to be executed while you are in the static initialization block.

Comment: Because the method reference contains information on both the instance and the method (or the class and the method for static methods). There is no "fill this later" option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The key is to defer the specification of `this` or to be more specific: The particular instance on which a method is to be called. So instead of storing method references directly we store functions that accept an instance and return a method reference for that instance.

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass {
    static Map<MyEnum, Function<MyClass, Consumer<String>>> methodMapping;
    static {
        methodMapping = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);
        methodMapping.put(MyEnum.FIRST, t -> t::firstMethod);
        methodMapping.put(MyEnum.SECOND, t -> t::secondMethod);
    }
    private String id;
    public MyClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    void firstMethod(String param) {
        System.out.println(id + ", 1st method, " + param);
    }
    void secondMethod(String param) {
        System.out.println(id + ", 2nd method, " + param);
    }
    void dispatchMethod(MyEnum myEnum, String param) {
        methodMapping.get(myEnum).apply(this).accept(param);
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass("MyInstance");
        MyClass.methodMapping.get(MyEnum.FIRST).apply(instance).accept("Using mapping directly");
        instance.dispatchMethod(MyEnum.SECOND, "Using dispatch method");
    }

}
```

Ideally `methodMapping` should be shielded against direct access from other classes so I'd suggest taking the `dispatchMethod` approach and making `methodMapping` private and immutable.